# Django - return multiple querysets in view

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Django 1.10

In my view, I have a function `get_queryset()` that, currently, returns one queryset. This function is called from another function, `get_context()`, which takes that data, uses it to get some values, and returns everything to the front end.

However, I now want to return 2 querysets from `get_queryset()`, one that is the full queryset and one that has a filter applied to it.

I assumed I could simply do something like:

```
full_results = query.all()
# do some filtering
filter_results = full_results.someFilter()

return full_results, filter_results
```

However, I have another function where these results get sent to FIRST before being sent to the front end. I figured I would be able to access these querysets easily with bracket notation, like this -

`faceted = self.get_queryset()[0].facet('thing')`

However! Turns out that I am unable to do so. I am trying to access a property on each item in the queryset in this second django function but am getting an error -

`AttributeError: 'SearchQuerySet' object has no attribute 'feature'`

So clearly I am doing something wrong.  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? Or would it be better to just make another function to return this data?

Comment: How about just using your view's `get_context_data()` function to do what it is you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only return a single queryset from `get_queryset`. But `get_context_data` itself can be extended to add whatever you like.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['filter_results'] = context['full_results'].someFilter()
    return context
```

Comment: I see! I didn't think about doing it like this but this seems to be way easier. Thanks Daniel, gonna try this out!